# Error during update Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

I have tried to update Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. I make sure that all updates have been installed. I used this manual for update: https://www.linuxtechi.com/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-ubuntu-20-04-lts/
However, on upgrade stage I got such error:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

Logs contain following info:
main.log

```
2020-09-16 15:03:36,501 INFO uname information: 'Linux Squirrel-PC 4.15.0-117-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 20:02:41 UTC 2020 x86_64'
2020-09-16 15:03:36,888 INFO apt version: '1.6.12ubuntu0.1'
2020-09-16 15:03:36,889 INFO python version: '3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
[GCC 8.4.0]'
2020-09-16 15:03:36,892 INFO release-upgrader version '20.04.25' started
2020-09-16 15:03:36,903 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2020-09-16 15:03:36,950 INFO screen could not be run
2020-09-16 15:03:36,981 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2020-09-16 15:03:37,027 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2020-09-16 15:03:37,055 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2020-09-16 15:03:40,110 DEBUG lsb-release: 'bionic'
2020-09-16 15:03:40,110 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2020-09-16 15:03:40,111 DEBUG openCache()
2020-09-16 15:03:40,111 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2020-09-16 15:03:40,111 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2020-09-16 15:03:41,145 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-117 with 
2020-09-16 15:03:41,146 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-54 with 4.15.0-117
2020-09-16 15:03:41,399 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 99430
2020-09-16 15:03:41,399 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'xubuntu-core')
2020-09-16 15:03:41,399 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2020-09-16 15:03:41,400 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2020-09-16 15:03:42,599 DEBUG openCache()
2020-09-16 15:03:43,644 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-117 with 
2020-09-16 15:03:43,645 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-54 with 4.15.0-117
2020-09-16 15:03:43,907 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 99430
2020-09-16 15:03:43,907 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2020-09-16 15:03:43,907 DEBUG quirks: running focalPostInitialUpdate
2020-09-16 15:03:43,907 DEBUG running Quirks.focalPostInitialUpdate
2020-09-16 15:03:46,989 DEBUG MetaPkgs: xubuntu-core
2020-09-16 15:03:49,786 DEBUG Foreign: 
2020-09-16 15:03:49,786 DEBUG Obsolete: aspnetcore-runtime-2.2 containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-2.2 dotnet-runtime-2.2 dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2 dotnet-sdk-2.2 libsstp-api-0 network-manager-sstp network-manager-sstp-gnome oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default packages-microsoft-prod sstp-client
2020-09-16 15:03:49,786 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2020-09-16 15:03:49,793 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2020-09-16 15:03:49,793 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2020-09-16 15:03:49,793 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2020-09-16 15:03:49,794 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2020-09-16 15:03:49,796 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,796 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted
2020-09-16 15:03:49,796 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/Release
2020-09-16 15:03:49,796 DEBUG s='http' n='archive.ubuntu.com' p='/ubuntu/dists/focal/Release' q='' f=''
2020-09-16 15:03:49,889 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,889 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,890 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,891 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,891 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,891 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,891 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,891 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,891 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,891 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner'
2020-09-16 15:03:49,891 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner' is already set to new dist
2020-09-16 15:03:49,894 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2020-09-16 15:04:05,764 DEBUG openCache()
2020-09-16 15:04:06,519 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-117 with 
2020-09-16 15:04:06,519 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-54 with 4.15.0-117
2020-09-16 15:04:06,695 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 66155
2020-09-16 15:04:06,696 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'xubuntu-core')
2020-09-16 15:04:06,696 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2020-09-16 15:04:06,696 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2020-09-16 15:04:06,696 INFO installing python-is-python2 because python-minimal was installed
2020-09-16 15:04:06,696 DEBUG Installing 'python-is-python2' (python-minimal was installed on the system)
```

apt.log

```
Investigating (1) gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 -> 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 < none | 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @un uH > (>= 3.36.0)
  Considering gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 14 as a solution to gnome-shell:amd64 77
  MarkKeep gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 -> 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing gnome-shell:amd64 rather than change gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64
  MarkDelete gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
 Try to Re-Instate (1) gnome-settings-daemon:amd64
  MarkKeep gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu1.3 -> 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umU NPb Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) gdm3:amd64 < 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 -> 3.34.1-1ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gdm3:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.19.92)
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 77 as a solution to gdm3:amd64 15
  MarkKeep gdm3:amd64 < 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 -> 3.34.1-1ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing gdm3:amd64 rather than change gnome-shell:amd64
  MarkDelete gdm3:amd64 < 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 | 3.34.1-1ubuntu1 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) ubuntu-session:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 -> 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-common:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 | 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umH > (= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1)
  Considering gnome-session-common:amd64 4 as a solution to ubuntu-session:amd64 15
  MarkKeep ubuntu-session:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 -> 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing ubuntu-session:amd64 rather than change gnome-session-common:amd64
  MarkDelete ubuntu-session:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 | 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 10 as a solution to mutter:amd64 14
  MarkKeep mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back mutter:amd64 rather than change gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (1) plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64
  MarkKeep plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64 < 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2 -> 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) network-manager-gnome:amd64 < 1.8.10-2ubuntu3 -> 1.8.24-1ubuntu2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken network-manager-gnome:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR >
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 77 as a solution to network-manager-gnome:amd64 11
  MarkKeep network-manager-gnome:amd64 < 1.8.10-2ubuntu3 -> 1.8.24-1ubuntu2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
Broken network-manager-gnome:amd64 Depends on policykit-1-gnome:amd64 < none | 0.105-7ubuntu2 @un uH >
  Considering policykit-1-gnome:amd64 3 as a solution to network-manager-gnome:amd64 11
  Try Installing policykit-1-gnome:amd64 < none | 0.105-7ubuntu2 @un uH > before changing network-manager-gnome:amd64
    MarkInstall policykit-1-gnome:amd64 < none -> 0.105-7ubuntu2 @un uN > FU=0
 Try to Re-Instate (1) indicator-session:amd64
  MarkKeep indicator-session:amd64 < 17.3.20+17.10.20171006-0ubuntu1 -> 17.3.20+19.10.20190921-0ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) gnome-startup-applications:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 -> 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-startup-applications:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-common:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 | 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umH > (>= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1)
  Considering gnome-session-common:amd64 4 as a solution to gnome-startup-applications:amd64 7
  MarkKeep gnome-startup-applications:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 -> 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back gnome-startup-applications:amd64 rather than change gnome-session-common:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (1) gnome-session-common:amd64
  MarkKeep gnome-session-common:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 -> 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
 Try to Re-Instate (1) gnome-power-manager:amd64
  MarkKeep gnome-power-manager:amd64 < 3.26.0-1 -> 3.32.0-2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 < 18.04.1 -> 33-1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.33)
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 77 as a solution to gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 0
  MarkKeep gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 < 18.04.1 -> 33-1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 rather than change gnome-shell:amd64
Investigating (1) gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 < 0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3 -> 68ubuntu1~20.04.1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (< 3.37)
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 77 as a solution to gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 0
  MarkKeep gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 < 0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3 -> 68ubuntu1~20.04.1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 rather than change gnome-shell:amd64
Investigating (1) gnome-shell-pomodoro:amd64 < 0.13.4-2 -> 0.16.0-1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-shell-pomodoro:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.15)
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 77 as a solution to gnome-shell-pomodoro:amd64 0
  MarkKeep gnome-shell-pomodoro:amd64 < 0.13.4-2 -> 0.16.0-1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing gnome-shell-pomodoro:amd64 rather than change gnome-shell:amd64
  MarkDelete gnome-shell-pomodoro:amd64 < 0.13.4-2 | 0.16.0-1 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 < none -> 10.1-5 @un uN Ib >
Broken chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR >
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 77 as a solution to chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 0
  MarkKeep chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 < none -> 10.1-5 @un uN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 rather than change gnome-shell:amd64
Investigating (1) gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 < none -> 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @un uN Ib >
Broken gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (= 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)
  Considering gnome-shell:amd64 77 as a solution to gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 0
  MarkKeep gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 < none -> 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @un uN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 rather than change gnome-shell:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (1) fwupdate:amd64
  MarkKeep fwupdate:amd64 < 12-7~ubuntu18.04.3 -> 12-7 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) gnome-tweaks:amd64 < 3.28.1-1 -> 3.34.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-tweaks:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 < none | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @un uH >
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 0 as a solution to gnome-tweaks:amd64 0
  MarkKeep gnome-tweaks:amd64 < 3.28.1-1 -> 3.34.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back gnome-tweaks:amd64 rather than change gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64
Investigating (2) gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.0-1ubuntu1 -> 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
  Considering mutter:amd64 14 as a solution to gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 95
  Upgrading mutter:amd64 due to Breaks field in gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64
Investigating (2) mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 10 as a solution to mutter:amd64 14
  MarkKeep mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back mutter:amd64 rather than change gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (2) network-manager-gnome:amd64
Re-Instated network-manager-gnome:amd64 (2 vs 1)
 Try to Re-Instate (2) gnome-startup-applications:amd64
  MarkKeep gnome-startup-applications:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 -> 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
 Try to Re-Instate (2) gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64
  MarkKeep gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 < 18.04.1 -> 33-1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
 Try to Re-Instate (2) gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64
  MarkKeep gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 < 0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3 -> 68ubuntu1~20.04.1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
 Try to Re-Instate (2) gnome-tweaks:amd64
  MarkKeep gnome-tweaks:amd64 < 3.28.1-1 -> 3.34.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
```

Question is how to fix this error and continue upgrade to 20.04?